# Closing all child windows in MFC MDI applications

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mdi, mdichild

I am using an MFC MDI application. I want to close all child windows on a notification. For this purpose, I am using this code:

```
CMDIFrameWnd *pFrame = NULL;
    CMDIChildWnd *pChild = NULL;
    CDocTemplate* pDocTemplate = NULL;
    CDocument* pDoc = NULL;

    for (POSITION pos = AfxGetApp()->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition(); pos != NULL; )
    {
        pDocTemplate = AfxGetApp()->GetNextDocTemplate( pos );

        for (POSITION pos1 = pDocTemplate->GetFirstDocPosition(); pos1 != NULL; )
        {
            if (pos1 == NULL)
                break;
            CDocument* pDoc = pDocTemplate->GetNextDoc( pos1 );

            for (POSITION pos2 = pDoc->GetFirstViewPosition(); pos2 != NULL; )
            {
                CView* pView = (CSignalWindow*)pDoc->GetNextView( pos2 );
                pView->CloseWindow();
            }
        }
    }
```

When this code is executed, in debug mode, it looks its closing all window and UI show black screen in entire child window area.
I want to update this window area after closing all child windows.
How I can update this area?

Comment: What do you mean by 'update'?

Comment: I guess, you can call Invalidate() for the Child Frame. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970.aspx

Comment: It is the normal case, that when a window is closed or destroyed, that the corresponding parent window area is redrawn. There is no need for any action. If there is a problem when redrawing, you have some failures in you WM_PAINT handler.

Answer (score 2):

You should not close the view. Just close the parent frame.

```
POSITION posTemplate = AfxGetApp()->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
while (posTemplate != NULL)
{
    CDocTemplate *pDocTemplate = AfxGetApp()->GetNextDocTemplate(posTemplate);
    if (pDocTemplate == NULL)
        break;

    POSITION posDoc = pDocTemplate->GetFirstDocPosition();
    while (posDoc != NULL)
    {
        CDocument* pDoc = pDocTemplate->GetNextDoc(posDoc);
        if (pDoc == NULL)
            break;

        POSITION posView = pDoc->GetFirstViewPosition();
        while (posView != NULL)
        {
            CView* pView = pDoc->GetNextView(posView);
            if (pView == NULL)
                break;

            pView->GetParentFrame()->DestroyWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Because you want to close all, you just need to get the head of the lists and remove it.
Using DestroyWindow for the frame may delete more than one view, if you collect views in one child frame (ie. splitter window).

There should never be a problem in repainting, because the parent window always redraws its client area, when a child window is destroyed, as long as you don't use SetRedraw...